# Does Jil have an option to convert empty string into null when Deserialize method is called?

Tags: c#, jil

I need to deserialize a JSON using Jil; unfortunately the deserialization fails when it tries to convert an empty string into a `double?`.

Is there any `Option` to set in order to solve this problem?

I went through the official documentation, but I didn't find what I was looking for. Am I missing something?

```cs
public class MyData
{
    public string MyName{ get; set; }
    public double? MyValue{ get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        string json = "{\"MyName\":\"my_name\",\"MyValue\":\"\"}";
        MyData foo = Jil.JSON.Deserialize<MyData>(json); 
    }
}
```

I expect `foo.MyValue` to be `null` but it throws `Jil.DeserializationException: 'Expected a double value'` instead.